# COPY command to load from Amazon S3 syntax error at or near "iam_role"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

Copying csv from s3 to redshift results in:

```
Error: syntax error at or near "iam_role"
```

The code used is below:

```
copy public.t1
from 's3://mybucket/mydata' 
iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::0123456789012:role/MyRedshiftRole'
csv;
```

I am using SQL Workbench/J and PostgreSQL database.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't you need semicolon `;` at the end?

Comment: @Marcin, forgot to add that to the question. The error still stands.

Comment: Did you configure SQL Workbench/J to use a Redshift driver? See: [Connect to your cluster by using SQL Workbench/J - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/connecting-using-workbench.html)

Comment: @John Rotenstein, I followed this guide to Create and Connect to a PostgreSQL Database. [link](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/tutorials/create-connect-postgresql-db/). 

I've checked via the link you provided and the connection was successful.
Are there any other prerequisite tasks to be done before using the Copy command?
Note, I assigned the IAM role to the database.

Comment: The link you provided is for Amazon RDS, which is different to Amazon Redshift. Are you using the Redshift driver as referenced in the link I provided? Your error message suggests that it doesn't understand the format of Redshift-specific commands, so it might be driver-related.

Comment: @ John Rotenstein, I was using the wrong guide. Using the Redshift guide resolved the issue